# DBus error when running TeX-evince-sync-view

Tags: latex, auctex

I am trying to get my LaTeX *View* command to work properly in Emacs, but for some reason I just can make it happen.

Whenever I hit <kbd>C-C</kbd><kbd>C-C</kbd> and enter the *View* command, Emacs automatically suggests `TeX-evince-sync-view`. However when I confirm that command, the minibuffer hangs until it eventually spits out:

> D-Bus error: "Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying"

I have tried exporting my `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable, but if Emacs is able to connect to DBus as it seems to be (given the error message), this shouldn't be the issue. I've also had a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs) and a few other pages, but I couldn't get rid of that error.

In the meantime, whenever I want to run a *View* command, I have to erase the default `TeX-evince-sync-view` and manually type in `evince document.pdf` which gets annoying after  while. I have also tried [making this other command the default *View* command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58435/change-default-emacs-view-command), but no matter what I do about this, Emacs still gives me `TeX-evince-sync-view` every time.

A few other things:

- I am using Emacs 25.3.1 on Arch Linux
- My AuCTeX version is 12.1.1 (used to be 11.92.0, but nothing changed after the upgrade).
- I don't have any *View*-related config in my `~/.emacs`.
- I have upgraded all my packages just in case before asking here.

Any ideas? Ideally I'd like `TeX-evince-sync-view` to work, but if it doesn't I'd like the simple `evince` command to pop up as the default.

Comment: Hi John. Since we're both Linux and TeX users, and you posted this, I thought you might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481892/3406. Can you reproduce this? And if so, any idea why (a) it's happening (b) ideas how to unstick dbus?

Answer (score 3):

Some playing around with `dbus-monitor` got me an answer for that one after all. Apologies for being off-topic: the problem wasn't coming from Emacs.

Looking at the output, it appeared that Emacs was indeed calling an Evince DBus method for `org.gnome.evince.Daemon`. I actually had no idea that Evince came with a daemon (`evinced`) so I took the liberty of looking for it in `/usr`. I came across the Evince systemd user unit, which manages `/usr/lib/evince/evinced`.

A look at `systemctl --user status evinced` then gave me:

```
systemd: Starting Evince document viewer...
systemd: Started Evince document viewer.
evinced: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
evinced: Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Which means that the request does indeed reach the Evince daemon, however the latter fails to connect to the Xorg display (fine, whatever), and to report its error via DBus (thanks...).

A closer look at the error will actually reveal that `evinced` does not have a name for the display, which is why it cannot reach it. This means the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not available when it starts. Indeed, if I have a look at..

```
$ systemctl --user show-environment
```

`DISPLAY` is nowhere to be found (same for `XAUTHORITY`). This can easily be fixed with one of these:

```
$ systemctl --user set-environment DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" XAUTHORITY="$XAUTHORITY"
$ dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
```

depending on whether you prefer to act at the DBus or systemd level. As a matter for fact, this should be done by default when you start your X server (see `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh`). In my case, since I wrote my own `.xinitrc`, that script is not run. If you use `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` as a template for this file, then the `systemd-user` script will be called. In my case, I fixed the issue by adding the following to my own `.xinitrc` file, which is all I was missing from the template:

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi
```

For more information, [have a look here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit#xinitrc).